# MSSQL server select into

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 20 millions rows and I need to create another table
off of it. but `select into` new table only inserts 100K records.

I have tried select into it and select table as

```
select * INTO #test
from dbo.log
```

New table should have 20 millions rows

Comment: how do you know? evaluate `@@ROWCOUNT` and how do you execute? SSMS? any text output?

Comment: select * INTO #test from dbo.log, it only inserts 100K rows. I do a count on id and that's the count 100k. if I do a count on id on source I get 20m. I also tried insert into but the same result. I am not sure if there is a limitation. database is in simple recovery mode.I also tried CTE and WITH (TABLOCK). but still only inserts 100k.

Comment: `set rowcount 0` before running your select into, something must've set your rowcount to 100k - it's the only way your query wouldn't select the whole table without throwing an error

Comment: can you capture the actual execution plan for the insert and upload it?

Comment: set rowcount 0 did the trick. not sure why was set to 100k. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Tables in temp db are very similar to the one available on regular databases. The table may be restricted with disk space available.

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM dbo.log

-- checking actual number of rows affected by query above
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Comment: yes, I did that but it only inserts 10007 records. not 20Millions. not sure how to do it.

Comment: @danielcaceres Do you have WHERE condition in your query?

Comment: no is a strait forward select into select * INTO #temp
from dbo.log.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @gordy's [ROWCOUNT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) suggestion, you could be looking at the *wrong* #temp table.

Consider:

```
select top 10 * into #foo from sys.objects

exec ('select * into #foo from sys.objects')

select count(*) from #foo
```

The nested batch creates a transient temp table called #foo that is destroyed at the end of the batch.  This would happen calling a stored procedure too.